# How to use Application.OnKey for Command-X on Excel 2016/2019 for Mac?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a Macro-Enabled Excel Workbook for use on both Windows and Mac. I am trying to detect when the user tries to use Cut, Copy, and Paste, because I want to disable these features so they don't accidentally copy over a formula that is important.

On Excel 2011 for Mac, I can, for instance, use the following code to detect if the user presses Command-C (for copy).

```
Application.OnKey "*c"
```

However, on Excel 2016/2019/365 for Mac, this doesn't work.  It seems the code has no effect.

How can I detect if the user presses Command-C (as well as Command-X & Command-V) on a Mac running Excel 2016/2019?

UPDATE: I have received confirmation that in Excel 2016/2019/365 for Mac, there is currently no way to detect if the Command key is pressed (as of 4/30/2019).  However, MS engineers are aware of this and may consider fixing it in later versions.

Comment: Is there any reason why you wouldn’t just protect the cells you don’t want them to update?

Comment: I have done that already, but for instance, if a user "cuts" a cell that is not protected (say A1) and pastes it into a another cell that is also not protected, the background color of A1 is removed, and I don't want that to happen.